# Cross Browser perspective solution?

Tags: css, cross-browser, position, perspective

**What the problem is**

I have tested this scenario of perspective usage ( a w3C validated webpage with all necessary and optional CSS browser tags) in IE, Firefox, Chrome, and Opera and found different (all inaccurate) results. So far it appears that the web browsers have all implemented perspective with slightly different displays. This question is here to see if maybe I'm missing something and there is a cross browser solution available.

**If no one has a solution, well then, we have an interesting situation. Before now, I've never seen a feature in CSS that acts noticeably and irreparably inaccurate between all browsers.**

**I hope I'm wrong,** *because if not, I have to create and maintain three separate style sheets via php or javascript browser checking, a method that is very clearly out of date and frowned upon in today's web design. We prefer to use Modernizr to check features rather than browsers now, but this situation would prove that solution inviable.*

**Example Situation:**

In Chrome, I positioned an iPhone interface simulating the use of a particular home automation app on the phone to control the channel of the tv in the background (an actual video), where the tv and iphone are made to look like they are part of the image with perspective and transform.

However, when looking at this from Firefox, the elements are completely out of place, as you can see below.

**Question:**

*Is there any cross browser solution that will allow me to produce this result without using separate style sheets for different browsers?*

**Live JS Fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/qZSYy/1/

**Purpose:**

I'm developing a website for a technology company, and one of the main services provided is home automation. With a remote, or an iPhone or iPad, you can control a home's lighting, music, tv, etc. Very cool. So, I've decided to develop a section of the home automation page that simulates this.

On Chrome, it looks like this right now:

[image]

On Firefox:

[image]

**Notes:**

The iphone screen is actually a separate element, that turns on when hovered over and remains  lit up for 10 seconds. I'm designing an interface on the iphone that will control the room's different lights, the speakers, and the tv, which is actually a separate div also that can be controlled by the iPhone as well to change channels.

The background is an image that I've render through Blender and can render different versions for the lighting changes.

**CSS:**

```
.home-auto-interactive {
width: 1250px;
height: 700px;
background-color: gray;
background-image: url('http://www.testing.agcomputers.net/style/images/Room_1.jpg');

-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-perspective: 80;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.home-auto-wrap {
width: 100%;
background-color: #252525;
}

.tv-screen {
width: 8.12%;
height: 7.8%;
position: absolute;

-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform .5s;
-o-transition: -o-transform .5s;
-ms-transition: -ms-transform .5s;
transition: transform .5s;

-webkit-transform: rotateY(-2deg) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateX(626.7%)    translateY(490%);
-moz-transform: rotateY(-2deg) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateX(626.7%) translateY(490%);
-o-transform: rotateY(-2deg) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateX(626.7%) translateY(490%);
-ms-transform: rotateY(-2deg) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateX(626.7%) translateY(490%);
transform: rotateY(-2deg) rotateX(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) translateX(626.7%) translateY(490%);
}

.iphone-screen {
width: 22.7%;
background-color: black;
background-image: url('http://www.testing.agcomputers.net/style/images/iphone_screen_test.jpg');

-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 50.8%;
bottom: 12.7%;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;

-webkit-transition-delay: 10s !important;
-moz-transition-delay: 10s !important;
-o-transition-delay: 10s !important;
-ms-transition-delay: 10s !important;
transition-delay: 10s !important;

-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
-o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
transition: opacity 0.5s;

-webkit-transform: rotateY(-0.75deg) rotateX(1deg) rotateZ(-3deg) translateX(18.5%) translateY(0%);
-moz-transform: rotateY(-0.75deg) rotateX(1deg) rotateZ(-3deg) translateX(18.5%) translateY(0%);
-o-transform: rotateY(-0.75deg) rotateX(1deg) rotateZ(-3deg) translateX(18.5%) translateY(0%);
-ms-transform: rotateY(-0.75deg) rotateX(1deg) rotateZ(-3deg) translateX(18.5%) translateY(0%);
transform: rotateY(-0.75deg) rotateX(1deg) rotateZ(-3deg) translateX(18.5%) translateY(0%);
}

.iphone-screen:hover {
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;

-webkit-transition-delay: 0s !important;
-moz-transition-delay: 0s !important;
-o-transition-delay: 0s !important;
-ms-transition-delay: 0s !important;
transition-delay: 0s !important;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="home-auto-wrap">
<div class="home-auto-interactive"><!-- begin home auto interactive :: this has the purpose of displaying an interactive home automation area -->
<div class="tv-screen"><!-- begin tv screen -->
    <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9NFUgVa68hw?autoplay=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&disablekb=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div><!-- end tv screen -->
<div class="iphone-screen"><!-- begin iphone screen -->

</div><!-- end iphone screen -->
</div><!-- end home auto interactive -->
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't change the image's perspective in Photoshop?

Comment: It's not an image, it's an actual interactive interface in the final design

Comment: @j08691 The iphone actually has an interactive control interface that changes the tv channel, music, lighting, etc.

Comment: Live example here, non official, since this page will change in the future. http://www.testing.agcomputers.net/RTI.php - For official reference, see the jsFiddle

Comment: But you could break it up into multiple images, for each button. May not be the solution you are looking for, but could be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `transform-style: preserve-3d;` on the parent element. Also place the perspective property here, more on that later:

```
.home-auto-wrap {
width: 100%;
background-color: #252525;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
perspective: 80px;
}
```

This is part of the problem as Firefox requires it, Chrome does not - this explains why it works there. The next issue with Firefox is that `overflow: hidden` set on `.home-auto-interactive` causes all descendant elements to be flattened according to the spec: [W3C Transform-style](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-transforms-20120911/#transform-style).

A workaround for this is to place the divs `.tv-screen` and `.iphone-screen` after `.home-auto-interactive` and position them atop. Now the 2 divs you are transforming will not be impeded.

Also opacity other than 1 will cause any descendant elements to flatten in 3D transforms, so be careful to keep that property for a div in the body with no transforming children (use z-index to position elements behind or in front of said div), or on the last node of a transforming element itself.

The background image property is not animatable, so you need to use an image tag to pull this off.

The issues you cite with TV could be due to:

1. The iframe, try applying the class to the iframe, though it should work as is.
2. The extra 0 transforms, get rid of these regardless.
3. The whole overflow thing, check the link above if you haven't done so.

Also, the filter property set other than none can lead to the same issue as the overflow and opacity, once again as per spec. It is not needed since IE 9, so unless you have some fallback reasons for doing so, removal is a good thing to consider. The opacity property has the same or better support than the 3D transforms:

[Can I use opacity](http://caniuse.com/css-opacity), check the 3d transforms too, I can't post more links yet. While you are at that page, check out the HTML5 video tag, it also has browser support as good as the 3d tranforms.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need another prefix. Anywhere you call `-webkit-perspective`, you also need to call `-moz-perspective`. And the perspective needs a value: ems, px, etc..

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective
http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/

This gave the elements perspective, but when you use `position:absolute;`, you need to also give a parent a defined `position` like `position:relative;`.

http://jsfiddle.net/NyXSa/7/

```
.home-auto-interactive {
    width: 1250px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: gray;
    background-image: url('http://www.testing.agcomputers.net/style/images/Room_1.jpg');

    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 80px;
    -moz-perspective: 80px;
    perspective: 80px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: According to mdn, it will work with Opera 15 aka webkit Opera.

Comment: Yes, but a large part of user refused to upgrade to opera 14/15 and still use the 12 version. further versions removed IRC client; mail client; opera Unite: opera links; opera turbo and many other features. Of course, t0dd can go ahead and day it's their problems to not follows web standards, But actually, it is presto which is fully compliant with CSS3 animations: You don't use any -webkit or -moz prefix. For my part most sites are still working, and didn't see any reason for downgrading, it may change in the future, but millions users will ignore websites like this rather than changing.

Comment: @JasonLydon in Firefox your edit almost fixes the issue, however as shown in the jsfiddle, the tv screen is weirdly not being fixed as neatly as the phone screen.

Comment: Are you sure about the perspective needing a prefix? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp - It doesn't look that way

Comment: Update `.tv-screen { ... top:5px; left:7px; ..}`. MDN is a better resource then w3schools.

Comment: @JasonLydon that fixes firefox but breaks chrome

Comment: This isn't a cross browser solution. It's progress, but not a viable solution, since I'll still have to create a separate style sheet for each browser type.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NyXSa/9/ That fiddle looks the same in Firefox 24, Chrome 32 and Safari 7 so you won't need a different stylesheet for those browsers. I wonder how this thread justifies a down vote, it appears to answer the question and stay on topic.